# How to disable cookies and clear cache in Chrome Custom Tabs?

Tags: android, cookies, chrome-custom-tabs

I am using Chromium 65 code. And want to open a 3rd party link by chrome custom tab, but not display data in Chromium browsing history. How to change the Chromium code?

I added

`customTabsIntent.intent.putExtra(IntentHandler.EXTRA_OPEN_NEW_INCOGNITO_TAB, true),`

but it seems not work.

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently possible to open a Chrome Custom Tab in Incognito mode.